# Is the "Configuration Service for .NET Applications and WCF Services" sample production-ready?

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration, enterprise, production

I recently stumbled across the [Configuration Service for.NET Applications and WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd164388).   It is part of the "StockTrader 4.0" sample put out by Microsoft.  I'm wondered if anyone has either used or adapted this service for a production enterprise application.  Is it enterprise-ready?  How would it compare to a commercial solution such as SO-Aware.

Comment: The fact that there is a [Stock Trader 5.0](https://azurestocktrader.cloudapp.net/) (Azure) version out there now would make me leery of the code. Also, it appears to integrate load distribution through configuration. Load balancing should be an infrastructure concern not an application concern besides dedicated hardware/software can do it better.

Comment: Please explain what are your parameters for enterprise-ready? Are you asking whether or not Microsoft intends for this to be an enterprise solution versus sample code?

Comment: @Ethan Don't really care what MS intends, more interested in whether anyohene has used it successfully in a production application.  I want to use it to centralize configuration, mainly WCF config, but some other app settings-type stuff as well.  My "application" is really about a dozen separate applications that each need some amount of app/web.config, which I would like to reduce to a minium.

Comment: Take a look at Tellago SO-Aware instead, if you want to centralize WCF configuration.

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Comment: No, apparently it's not a "real question" to certain pedants.  However, I have heard basically nothing of this since my initial research, which makes me believe that it is a proof-of-concept that never really went anywhere.